# Is it OK to read len(ch) messages from channel ch?

Tags: go

I'm running single goroutine to handle messages channel related to some user. After processing messages the user state is updated and stored in database by the goroutine. While request to database is in progress a number of messages can be sent to the channel. I would like to process them all before sending another request to the database.

Currently I'm using `len(ch)` to check number of messages in the channel and reading them in a for loop.

```golang
func (c *consumer) handleUser(userID string, ch chan Message) {
  user := c.db.LoadUser(userID)
  for {
    var msgs []Message
    for n := len(ch); n > 0; n-- {
      msgs = append(msgs, <-ch)
    }
    apply.Messages(user, msgs)
    c.db.SaveUser(user)
}

ch := make(chan Message, 100)
go c.handleUser("user-1", ch)
```

I was searching in the internet if this is some common pattern but I couldn't find similar solutions and I'm wondering if my approach is valid/idiomatic for go programs.

Comment: The idiomatic way to do this is to use a `chan []Message`; or one goroutine per update, which looks for the channel to be closed.

Comment: No, it's not OK; channels are a concurrency mechanism, which means that while you're receiving from the channel, its length may be changing. Trying to do what you're doing also implies an inherently flawed design; if you want to batch messages, don't use the channel buffer to batch them, use something in the worker (like a slice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution would cause the spawned goroutine to spin over the channel until at least one message is sent. In other words, the goroutine never blocks at all.

Here you are trying to process multiple messages in one batch. There are different ways to implement that. But the main question to answer is: *how do you know that the batch of messages is complete?* The sender goroutine might have this knowledge and it can pack all the messages in one slice. On the other hand, you might not know when the batch is ready. In those cases, you need to use a timeout, like the following example.

```
func (c *consumer) handleUser(userID string, ch chan Message) {
    user := c.db.LoadUser(userID)
    for {
        var msgs []Message
        select {
        case msg := <-ch:
            //Append the message in the current batch slice
            msgs = append(msgs, msg)
        //Wait up to 5 seconds and then process the batch
        case <-time.After(time.Second * 5):
            //Timeout: process the batch of messages
            if len(msgs) > 0 {
                apply.Messages(user, msgs)
                c.db.SaveUser(user)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that a possible goroutine executing this function runs only when there is actually something to do.